# Serial Communication between Raspberry and Arduino, C++

Tags: c++, serialization, arduino, raspberry-pi

Good Morning Everybody,

A subtask of my Semester Project requires me to have a serial Communication between an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi 3. I am not very experienced in Programming, only had one Semester in C++. I found a nice Library called wiringSerial, which presets all the preferences for the Serial communication. Now to my Problem - If I write to the Serial Port manually (Terminal, using `echo a > /dev/ttyUSB0`) I get the expected and correct response. If however, I use my program written in C++ I get complete rubbish or nothing back. I would be extremely grateful if one of you guys could help me out. Here is the code:

**Arduino Side:**

```
#include "Arduino.h"

int PIN_NUMBER; 
int BAUD_RATE=9600;
int PROBLEM_LED=2; 

int PWM_PINS[]={3, 5, 6, 9}; //x+: 3, x-: 5, y+: 6, y-: 9; 

const int PIN_COUNT=4;
const int MAX_VOLT=5;

const char XPLUS_MASK = 0x62;
const char XMINUS_MASK = 0x63;
const char YPLUS_MASK = 0x64;
const char YMINUS_MASK = 0x65;
const char ACK_MASK = 0x60;
const char INIT_MASK = 0x61;
bool initialized = false;

const char MASK[]={XPLUS_MASK, XMINUS_MASK, YPLUS_MASK, YMINUS_MASK};

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);

  while(!Serial); 

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    pinMode(PWM_PINS[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(PROBLEM_LED, OUTPUT);

}

void decode(char opCode, char value){

  if((!initialized && ((opCode & INIT_MASK))!=INIT_MASK)){
    Serial.write(0); 
    return; 
    }

  else if(((opCode & INIT_MASK))==INIT_MASK){
    Serial.write(ACK_MASK); 
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      analogWrite(PWM_PINS[i], 0);
    }
    Serial.flush(); 
    initialized=true; 
    return; 
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    if((opCode & MASK[i])==MASK[i]){
      analogWrite(PWM_PINS[i], value); 
    Serial.write(ACK_MASK); 
    return;       
    }
  }



  return; 
}


void loop() {
  char opCode=0;
  char value=0;  

  if(Serial.available()==1){ 
    opCode=Serial.read(); 
    decode(opCode, 0);
  }

  else if(Serial.available()>=2){
    opCode=Serial.read(); 
    value=Serial.read();
    Serial.read();
    decode(opCode, value);
  }
  while(Serial.available()){
    Serial.read();

  }

 delay(100);
}
```

**Raspberry Side:**

```
#include "ArdPiComm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

ArdPiComm::ArdPiComm(){

    INIT_BYTE=0x61;
    XPLUS_MASK=0x62;
    XMINUS_MASK=0x63;
    YPLUS_MASK=0x64;
    YMINUS_MASK=0x65;
    ACK_MASK=0x60;
    BAUD_RATE=9600;
    PORT="/dev/pts/7\0";
    fd=0;
    MASKS[0]=XPLUS_MASK;
    MASKS[1]=XMINUS_MASK;
    MASKS[2]=YPLUS_MASK;
    MASKS[3]=YMINUS_MASK;
}
ArdPiComm::ArdPiComm(char* port, int baud_rate) {

    INIT_BYTE=0x61;
    fd=0;
    XPLUS_MASK=0x62;
    XMINUS_MASK=0x63;
    YPLUS_MASK=0x64;
    YMINUS_MASK=0x65;
    ACK_MASK=0x60;
    BAUD_RATE=baud_rate;
    PORT=port;


}
ArdPiComm::~ArdPiComm() {
    delete this;
}
void ArdPiComm::close(){
    serialClose(fd);
    return;
}

bool ArdPiComm::INIT(){

        fd=serialOpen("/dev/ttyUSB0\0", 9600);

        unsigned char rt=0;

        serialPutchar(fd, 0x61);
        serialFlush(fd);

        while((serialDataAvail(fd))==0);
        rt=serialGetchar(fd);

        if((rt&ACK_MASK)==ACK_MASK){
            std::cout << "Connection established. ";
            return true;
        }
        std::cout << "Connection not Acknowledged. Please Retry.";
        return false;
    }

    /*---------------------- steer function --------------------------
     * PRE: Input is an Array of Dimensions 1x4, where A[0] X+, A[1] X-, A[2] Y+, A[3] Y-.
     * The Values Stored in the Array are ranging from 0-255 describing the deviance from the 0
     * point on corresponding axis
     * POST: If write was sucessful, output is true, else it is false
     ---------------------------------------------------------------*/

    bool ArdPiComm::send(int A[]){

        unsigned char value=0;
        unsigned int rt=0;

        for(int k=0; k<4; k++){


            if(A[k] > 255){
                std::cout << "Value too large, please input value between 0 and 255\n";
                return false;
            }

            value=(A[k] & 0xFF);

            //write the Destination and then the value;

            serialPutchar(fd, MASKS[k]);
            serialPutchar(fd, value);
            serialFlush(fd);

            // getting ACK
            while(serialDataAvail(fd)==0);      //spinning

            rt=serialGetchar(fd);
            rt= rt & ACK_MASK;


            if(rt!=ACK_MASK){
                std::cout << "Failed to acknowledge. Please retry\n ";
                return false;
            }

            if(rt==ACK_MASK){
                std::cout << "Received loud and clear. Please Proceed.\n ";
                return true;
            }


            else {
                std::cout << "no idea what happend. Revise your code\n";
                return false;
            }


        }

        return true;
    }
```

Sorry for the bad commentation. This was supposed to work without any problems :P 
Thank you very much for your time.

Kind Regards, 
Killian

p.s.: here is the link for the source code of the library: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/wiringPi/wiringSerial.c